# IntelliJ opens java.lang classes despite it does not steps in them during debugging

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have set that IntelliJ should not step into clasess from java.* and  javax.* packages during debugging (Settings - Build,Execution,Deployment - Debugger - Stepping - Do not step into the classes) so it does not step into  but it still opens them so after just a few of steps of debugging I end up with many opened classes. Is there any option to avoid that?

Comment: Are you using force step in while debugging?

Comment: How does happen? I mean you say IDE does not step into them but they are still opened?

Comment: It steps in but immediately steps out.